# Cannot install uasyncio package on esp32 using upip

Tags: pypi, esp32, micropython

I have been using uasyncio on ESP32-WROOM-32D. After all the testing, I am trying to use the firmware to my other boards but uasyncio is not installed by default with the micropython. I tried to install the package by

```
>rshell -p comX 
>repl
>>> import upip
>>> upip.install('micropython-uasyncio')
```

but getting the following error:

```
Installing to: /lib/
Error installing 'micropython-uasyncio': list index out of range, packages may be partially installed
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a network error. I traced the same error and found that `usocket.getaddrinfo` failed to return a sensible address, leading to a list out of range exception in the upip module (https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/master/tools/upip.py#L136).

Check your network configuration using:

```
import network
network.WLAN(network.STA_IF).ifconfig()
```

If settings are not correct, make sure you have reasonable settings by calling [ifconfig](http://docs.micropython.org/en/v1.9.3/pyboard/library/network.html?highlight=ifconfig#network.ifconfig) with a tuple of 4 addresses (ip, mask, gateway, dns):

```
network.WLAN(network.STA_IF).ifconfig(("192.168.1.101", "255.255.255.0", "192.168.1.1", "8.8.8.8"))
```